# Angular 7: How to re-write nested subscribtions?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular7

I have a component that displays a filtered list of items. It is subscribed to two observables - the first one is for (filter) parameters that need to be passed into the second observable to get the filtered list of items.

```
public filteredItems = [];

this.myService.getFilterParams()
   .subscribe(params => {
       this.myService.getFilteredItems(params)
         .subscribe(items => { this.filteredItems = items});
   });
```

I've read that chaining subscribtion is not the best practice (the code works fine otherwise), so how can I re-write it?

Comment: it depends upon what does `myService.getFilteredItems` does it make http calls? and which version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: yes, it calls myService.getItems (it just applies filter params to it), which makes http calls. I'm using rxjs version 6.5.2. Thank you very much for your willingness to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `mergeMap` or `switchMap` to achieve this. Difference is that `switchMap` will cancel inner subscription if outer subscription emits new values, `mergeMap` won't.

```js
this.myService
    .getFilterParams()
    .pipe(mergeMap(params => this.myService.getFilteredItems(params)))
    .subscribe(items => {
        this.filteredItems = items;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use switchMap, mergeMap, concatMap higher order operators here.

1. Use mergeMap if your first observable will emit multiple values and you want to collect responses from all the inner observables in the subscribe function. Also it will send the requests in parallel and the order will not be maintained when getting response in subscribe.
2. You can also use concatMap which will send the first request collect the response and then send the second request for your inner observable.

Looking at your code i suggest to use switchMap which will cancel any new values are emitted from your first observable and only last inner observable value is received in your subscribe.

Also tap the response to do any intermediate steps if needed.

Hope this helps.

```
this.myService
    .getFilterParams()
    .pipe(
         tap( (res) => {
           // do any intermediate steps 
           console.log(res);
         }),
         switchMap(params => this.myService.getFilteredItems(params))
     )
     .subscribe(items => {
         this.filteredItems = items;
     });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! I'm new to Angular and really appreciate such (rare) moments of insight that your answer has given me. I didn't checkmark your answer only because Evaldas was earlier and his reply also worked.

Comment: Great, even if it helped to a small extent, happy to help.