# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of null in NGRX Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

When I dispatching my action in my component this updateTour effect should be triggered. but this error appears in my browser console `core.js:5847 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of null at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (updatetour.effects.ts:87)`
`requestHandlerService.invoke(request).pipe` causing the error. can someone explain what's wrong here

```
updataTour$ = createEffect(() =>
   this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType(TourproviderAction.updateTourprovider),
       switchMap((action) => {
       const data = action.tourProvider;
       const parameters: any = { tourProviderId: '1' };
       const queryParams = new HttpParams({
              fromObject: parameters
       })

        const options = {
                params: queryParams,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'a5sfjdksfjksfe2f4af3673ce1a'
              }
         };

        const request = new ServiceRequest
       (environment.urls.tourProvider, 'POST', formData, options);
        return this.requestHandlerService.invoke(request).pipe(
                map((updateResponce) => {
             const responceData = JSON.stringify(updateResponce)
             return TourproviderAction.updateTourproviderSuccess({ responce: responceData });
                }),
                catchError(err => {
                    const errorMessage = JSON.stringify(err);
                    return of(TourproviderAction.updateTourproviderFail({ errorMessage }))
                })
            );
        })
    )
);
```

Comment: Is it this pipe `requestHandlerService.invoke(request).pipe` that's causing the error?

Comment: yes that is the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that this line

```js
this.requestHandlerService.invoke(request)
```

is returning null and cannot call pipe function. Make sure that you return Observable from invoke method so that you can pipe the reponses.

Comment: I want to know how these functions invoke. first this `this.requestHandlerService.invoke(request)` executed and after that is it gonna call `pipe()`?

Comment: Yes, it will first call this.requestHandlerService.invoke(request), retrieve the response and is passed to pipe operators.

Comment: You mostly would not need inner pipe, just return inner observables. Checkout stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-learnings?file=nested-subscribe.ts

Also check answer here to handle nested subscribes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562159/angular-7-how-to-re-write-nested-subscribtions/57567909#57567909

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

make sure requestHandlerService.invoke(request) returns Observables