# Test Broadcast Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular7, azure-ad-msal

Hi I am trying to write angular code for a component with an observable but I can't test the broadcast service. I get an error saying the service is not being called. How Should I access the service? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**This is my component with the observable:**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.subscription.add(
      this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:acquireTokenSuccess', (payload) => {
        // do something here
        this.roleService.checkServerEventReviewers().subscribe(res => {
          this.userService.userDetails.role = res ? 'Data Steward' : 'Mosaic Consumer';
          if (this.isLoggedIn !== true) {
            const redirectUri = sessionStorage.getItem('redirectUri');
            if (redirectUri !== undefined || redirectUri !== null) {
              this.router.navigateByUrl(redirectUri);
            }
          }
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
};
```

**This is my spec file that I am trying:**

```
    describe('AppComponent', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [RouterTestingModule],
         declarations: [AppComponent],
         providers: [WindowService, HttpClient, RoleService, UserService, HttpHandler, BroadcastService, MsalService,
        {
          provide: MSAL_CONFIG,  // MsalService needs config, this provides it.
          useFactory: () => ({   // Note this is an arrow fn that returns the config object
            redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
            clientID: mockData.clientID,
          }),
        }],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  describe(':', () => {
    function setup() {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      return {fixture, app, compiled};
    }

    it("Role should be Data Steward", fakeAsync (() => {
    const fn = 'msal:acquireTokenSuccess';
    const subscription = new Subscription();
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    const spyOnBS = spyOn(app.broadcastService,'subscribe');
    const roleServiceCall = 
    spyOn(app.roleService,'checkServerEventReviewers');
    app.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(spyOnBS).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(roleServiceCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
}));
```

Comment: You should most definetly try to clean up your code by removing subscribe inside a subscribe maybe this question helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562159/angular-7-how-to-re-write-nested-subscribtions
After that this should be easier to sort out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I read wrong the issue. (Response Updated).
I think that the problem is that you are testing an observable service. I think that you should use [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync) and [tick](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-tick-function) to test it.

```
    describe('AppComponent', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [RouterTestingModule],
         declarations: [AppComponent],
         providers: [WindowService, HttpClient, RoleService, UserService, HttpHandler, BroadcastService, MsalService,
        {
          provide: MSAL_CONFIG,  // MsalService needs config, this provides it.
          useFactory: () => ({   // Note this is an arrow fn that returns the config object
            redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
            clientID: mockData.clientID,
          }),
        }],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  describe(':', () => {
    function setup() {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      return {fixture, app, compiled};
    }

    it('Init with QA environment', fakeAsync(() => {
      const {app} = setup();
      spyOnBS = spyOn(app.broadcastService,'subscribe');
      spyOn(app.authService, 'getUser').and.returnValue(mockData.userDetails);
      spyOn(app.authService, 'acquireTokenSilent').and.returnValue('msal:acquireTokenSuccess');
      app.ngOnInit();
      tick();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
          expect(spyOnBS).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    ));
```

Try if that works.

Comment: I did include it in the test bed module. I just didn't add that part of the code to my question. It still does not run

Comment: Can you add all the content fo the spec file?

Comment: Done! I was thinking it wasn't being called because its inside a `subscription.add` but I am not exactly too sure

Comment: Thanks, I think that I found the problem. I have just updated my answer.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much. Is it possible I ask you for one more clarification?

Comment: Yes, do it. If you can add that clarification to the original question so if tomorrow someone has the same problem he will find the answer. Also, remember to mark as resolved when we finish the clarification.

Comment: If I wanted to test the role inside the `broadcastservice.subscribe` specifically this line of code `this.roleService.checkServerEventReviewers().subscribe(res => { this.userService.userDetails.role = res ? 'Data Steward' : 'Mosaic Consumer'; `. How would I do that?

Comment: In that case, you are not testing the component, in fact, you are testing the service, so you should add the correspondent test in the spec file of the userService. If you need help with that, please make another question (you can paste the link here) and I will help you with that.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to check if  `this.roleService.checkServerEventReviewers().subscribe` was called then if we can't test the role?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same approach that we use before.

Comment: I added the test in the spec file however it is failing, could you maybe take a look?

Comment: Make another question and I will answer you because here I don't have space to write spec file content.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864138/roleservice-not-being-called here is the link