# RoleService not being called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

Hi I am trying to write angular code for a component with an observable but I can't test the role service call inside the broadcast service. I get an error saying the service is not being called. How Should I access the service? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**This is my component with the observable:**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.subscription.add(
      this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:acquireTokenSuccess', (payload) => {
        // do something here
        this.roleService.checkServerEventReviewers().subscribe(res => {
          this.userService.userDetails.role = res ? 'Data Steward' : 'Mosaic Consumer';
          if (this.isLoggedIn !== true) {
            const redirectUri = sessionStorage.getItem('redirectUri');
            if (redirectUri !== undefined || redirectUri !== null) {
              this.router.navigateByUrl(redirectUri);
            }
          }
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
};
```

**This is my spec file that I am trying:**

```
    describe('AppComponent', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [RouterTestingModule],
         declarations: [AppComponent],
         providers: [WindowService, HttpClient, RoleService, UserService, HttpHandler, BroadcastService, MsalService,
        {
          provide: MSAL_CONFIG,  // MsalService needs config, this provides it.
          useFactory: () => ({   // Note this is an arrow fn that returns the config object
            redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
            clientID: mockData.clientID,
          }),
        }],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

    it("Role should be Data Steward", fakeAsync (() => {
    const fn = 'msal:acquireTokenSuccess';
    const subscription = new Subscription();
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    const spyOnBS = spyOn(app.broadcastService,'subscribe');
    const roleServiceCall = 
    spyOn(app.roleService,'checkServerEventReviewers');
    app.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(spyOnBS).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(roleServiceCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing error in your component file not spec file, then store this into local variable and use it with your roleService

Updated code will looks like

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    const that = this; // STORE this into local variable 

    this.subscription.add(
      this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:acquireTokenSuccess', (payload) => {
        ...
        // USE "that" instead of "this"
        that.roleService.checkServerEventReviewers().subscribe(res => {
          ...
        });
      });
    );
```

Comment: The issue still remains

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
   describe('AppComponent', () => {
      let mockBS: BehaviorSubject<MediaChange>;
      beforeEach(() => {
       mockBS = new BehaviorSubject();
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [RouterTestingModule],
         declarations: [AppComponent],
         providers: [WindowService, HttpClient, RoleService, UserService, HttpHandler, BroadcastService, MsalService,
        { provide: useValue: mockBS.asObservable() },
        {
          provide: MSAL_CONFIG,  // MsalService needs config, this provides it.
          useFactory: () => ({   // Note this is an arrow fn that returns the config object
            redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
            clientID: mockData.clientID,
          }),
        }],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it("Role should be Data Steward", fakeAsync (() => {
    const fn = 'msal:acquireTokenSuccess';
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    const roleServiceCall = spyOn(app.roleService,'checkServerEventReviewers');
    app.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      mockBS.next({});
      tick();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
         expect(roleServiceCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
}));
```

Comment: I still get this error *Expected spy checkServerEventReviewers to have been called*

Comment: Try now, i changed the ```spyOnBS.and.returnValue({});``` of place

Comment: I still get the same error. Would it be easier by any chance to check this line of code `const redirectUri = sessionStorage.getItem('redirectUri');`

Comment: My bad, I forget that ```broadcastService ``` returns an Observable.
Now I changed: ```spyOnBS.and.returnValue({}); ``` for ```spyOnBS.and.returnValue(of({}));``` with **of**  (```import { of } from 'rxjs';```)  we are returning an Observable.
Can you try now to see if it works?

Comment: I'll have to try it tomorrow, since I'm out of work. Will I be able to reach you tomorrow?

Comment: I hope yes. Try it and if it doesn't work we will try another thing.

Comment: I still get the same error. Do we have to return an expected type of observable?

Comment: What was the other method that you wanted to try?

Comment: First I need to ask, What returns the BroadcastService? Is it a Promise or an Observable? 
Can you add the code of the BroadcastService?

Comment: I am not too sure, its a service being imported from msal angular https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular

Comment: I have just updated my question.
I know that perhaps this test could break another test that uses BroadcastService ```(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860227/test-broadcast-service/58860923?noredirect=1#comment103998873_58860923)```
However, you can have more than one ```describe('AppComponent', () => {})```.
So you can have one describe with TestModule to Test the BroadcastService and another one to test this case.